# Laravel 4: php artisan server - write permissions?

Tags: php, http, laravel, laravel-4

I am currently running the laravel 4 development server using:

```
php artisan serve
```

Now when uploading a file into a folder, I guess it is not working, because the server has

no write permissions. How can I set write permissions on mac for artisan php serve?

For example on Linux I have apache apache as owner and group. What does artisan use. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the artisan `serve` command will run under the permissions of the currently logged in user. If you need to run it using any other user you'll have to tell your system:

```
sudo su - <loginname> php artisan serve
```

I'm not sure if you should run it as apache:

```
sudo su - www-data php artisan serve
```

or

```
sudo su - httpd php artisan serve
```

Because apache may not have the environment set to run php.

But you can simply run it as root:

```
sudo php artisan serve
```

And root has rights to write files pretty much everywhere in your system.